# Need to disable USB device

Tags: usb, webcam

My laptop has a built in camera. Ubuntu detects this as a pluged in USB device and turns on the power. One, I don't want the camera on all the time, feel like some one is watching me. Two, it starts to heat up the screen. It's a small camera, but does produce a lot of heat after about 10 minutes of running.

I've tried following steps I found on the internet, but no luck.

The command

> for device in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product); do echo $device;cat $device;done

Returns

> /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/product
>
> USB2.0 Camera
>
> /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/product
>
> BCM92045NMD
>
> /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/product
>
> Trackball
>
> /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/product
>
> EHCI Host Controller
>
> /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/product
>
> UHCI Host Controller
>
> /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/product
>
> UHCI Host Controller
>
> /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4/product
>
> UHCI Host Controller
>
> /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb5/product
>
> UHCI Host Controller

The command

> echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/power/level

Returns

> suspend
>
> tee: /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/power/level: Invalid argument

Answer (score 1):

Try this command,

```
sudo sh -c "echo suspend >> /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/power/level"
```

It appends the string `suspend` to the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/power/level` file.

If the file doesn't exists anymore then run the below command.It will create a file and then appends the string `suspend` to that file.

```
sudo sh -c "echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/power/level"
```

Comment: No change. System seems to not like 'suspend'.

Comment: I corrected only the command you tried.

Answer (score 0):

suspend is deprecated.
Use `echo 'x-y' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind` instead.
x,y are numbers you find from

```
`for device in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product); do echo $device;cat $device;done`
```